# Proving a number of properties of the infinite product.

Tags: complex-analysis

For a sequence of complex numbers $c_1, c_2...$, the infinite product $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k$$ is said to converge if there given $\epsilon>0$ exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ and all $p\geq 1$ $$|\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+p}c_k-1|<\epsilon$$

Now, I want to show the following properties of the infinite product:

1) If the infinite product converges, the sequence of partial product is bounded

2) If the infinite product converges, the sequence of partial products is a cauchy sequence(and thus a convergent sequence)

3) If the infinite product converges, the infinite product is $0$ if and only if atleast on factor $c_k=0$

These properties should be relatively easy to show but I still can't seem to figure out. I'm not sure about  1), but to show 2) I think you would use the boundedness of the partial products. In 3) one way seems trivial but the other not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_n$ be the product of the first $n$ factors: $p_n=c_1c_2...c_n$. Let $M$ be the maximum of the numbers $|p_1|,|p_2|,...,|p_N|$. For $n >N$ we have $|p_n| =|p_N| \prod_{k=N+1}^{n} |c_k|<M(1+\epsilon)$. It is clear from this that the sequence $(p_n)$ is bounded. Let $C$ be  abound for this sequence.

Next consider $|p_n-p_{n+j}|$ We can write this as $|p_n| |1-\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+j} |c_k||<C\epsilon$ for $n >N, j\geq 1$ proving 2).

It is obvious that if some $p_n=0$ the the infinite product is $0$. Now suppose $c_k \neq 0$ for any $k$. Then $|\frac {p_{N+j}} {p_N}|>1-\epsilon$ for all $j$ from which it follows that the in finite product is not $0$.